# What's wrong with my example?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I have been asked to show that if $V\subset k^n$ is an affine algebraic variety over an algebraically closed field $k$, and $dom(f) = V$ for some $f\in k(V)$ then $f$ lies in $k[V]$. Here, $k(V)$ is the field of rational functions on $V$ and $dom(f) = \{p\in V|f\quad \text{is regular}\}$.

However, if I consider $V = \mathbb{V}(y-x^2)\subseteq \mathbb{C}^2$ and $f = \frac{x}{1+y}\in\mathbb{C}(V)$, then $\forall p\in V, 1+y(p)\neq 0$. This implies $dom(f) = V$. However, $f$ does not lie in the coordinate ring, $k[V]$. Is there something wrong with my argument?

[Edit]:
Thanks to Zev for pointing out my flaw. I have a more fundamental question now. So, is it true that for every f=gh, g,h∈k[V],h≠constant, ∃p∈V such that h(p)=0 for an algebraically closed field k?

Thanks,
Kartik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is something wrong: the point $p=(i,-1)$ is in $V$ since $(-1)-(i)^2=0$, but $1+y(p)=1+(-1)=0$, so $f$ is not regular at $p$.

Comment: Thanks. I see your point, Zev. So, is it true that for every $f = \frac{g}{h}$, $g,h\in k[V], h\neq \text{constant}$, $\exists p\in V$ such that $h(p) = 0$ for an algebraically closed field $k$?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your new question -- whether a nonconstant polynomial $h \in k[V]$ necessarily vanishes on $V$ -- let $V$ be the hyperbola

$$x y = 1$$

in the plane.  Clearly $x \in k[V]$ is nonconstant -- it takes the value $1$ at the point $(1,1)$ and the value $2$ at the point $(2, \frac{1}{2})$.  On the other hand, it does not vanish at any point of $V$, because there is no point on the hyperbola with an $x$-coordinate of zero.